# mailchimp API 3.0, template html source

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am in the process of migrating from MailChimp API 2.0 to 3.0

One of the features I used in 2.0 was to retrieve the HTML source from a template https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/templates/info.php so I could preview how a proposed email would look, without having to create a campaign first.

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this with API 3.0

Comment: and your question is...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just answered this question over here - [mailchimp 3.0 Get template in html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222199/mailchimp-3-0-get-template-in-html-form/41066732#41066732)

There's no direct way of getting the source of a template (yet), but you can create a campaign with your templates and then get the source of that campaign.

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/content/

Answer (score 0):

You can get Mailchimp template HTML source using API 2.0

```
require_once('..includes/Mailchimp/Mailchimp.php');
$apiKey = "apikey-usx";
$mailchimpObj = new Mailchimp($apiKey);

printr($mailchimpObj->template['your template id here']);
echo "<pre>";
```

See the working API:
https://devsnook.com/get-mailchimp-template-html-content/

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question was about API 3.0, so this is not really an answer.